# How to change or override smtp_password for Google Composer Airflow

Tags: smtp, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to do a setup of smtp server in Google Composer Airflow, as per the google document smtp_password can not be overridden and default password should be used.

Is there any option to use smtp server with actual password in Google Cloud Composer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, some [Airflow configurations](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/airflow-configurations) are preconfigured for Cloud Composer and you cannot change them like **smtp-smtp_password** after the new environment is already created.

You can receive notifications by [configuring](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#override) **SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM** and **SENDGRID_API_KEY** environment variables to send email through the [SendGrid email](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#notification) service using the SendGrid API key instead of smtp_password.

Additionally, you can configure [third-party SMTP](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#configuring_third-party_smtp_services) services but consider that Cloud Composer does not support configuring the smtp_password because the value is stored in plain text in airflow.cfg and considered unsecure.

Comment: Thanks for the response ... if we use sendGrid, Is it secure to send business email via sendGrid. Can sendGrid decrypt the sent mail. Is it a fully secured system to use for business. Kindly please guide me on this.

Comment: Regarding your question, I think sendGrid is secure as it follow Opportunistic encryption using TLS. You can find more details in https://sendgrid.com/blog/sendgrid-and-the-future-of-email-security/ and https://sendgrid.com/policies/security/